# want to see a message on powershell ISE while executing .exe

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to execute this powershell script

```
Write-output `n "\\Latest Modified Mobile file is"
$dir = "\\sharepoint.amr.ith.intel.com@SSL\sites\peca\PTA Data Sandbox\Shared Documents\Under_review\Regina\Estimates"
$filter="*EstimateImport_Mobile_*.xlsx"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Name

if($?)
{
   "command succeeded"
}
else
{
   "command failed"
}

& "C:\PECA Data Estimates Importer\PECA Estimates Importer.exe" import -i $latest.FullName

if($?)
{
  "command succeeded"
}
else
{
 "command failed"
}

Start-Sleep -s 5

exit
```

when I am using the "&" operator, it runs some windows .exe tool but on the screen I don't see any message, I want to see a message like "Running tool" on a powershell ISE so that the user knows that the script is still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see output on the screen, don't use `Write-Output`.

Use `Write-Host` to write text that will always be seen. Use `Write-Verbose` to write text that will only be seen in verbose mode.

Comment: Even after personally editing the code blocks into the original question, I totally missed that the asker was utilizing `Write-Output`